# Is there an API into the NuGet datawarehouse?

Tags: api, rest, nuget

I am trying to get at the data from the [NuGet](http://nuget.org) gallery that would show package usage statistics. (Downloads over time, NuGet action per download etc.)

There is a [NuGet datawarehouse](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Warehouse) project on GitHub but I do not see any API to access it, so I'm assuming that it is purely to drive what is shown on the gallery website.

Is there an API other than https://api-v3search-0.nuget.org/query or the older https://nuget.org/api/v2 OData feed that can be used to get at NuGet package stats?

Comment: There are a set of api endpoints you can see - https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json - however you may get a better answer by asking this question on https://github.com/nuget/home so one of the NuGet team can respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is no. See this GitHub issue https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1829